# Why docker container can access my directory without -v flag?

Tags: docker

I was updating Docker and then it showed me a tutorial. Interested, I decided to see whether there are something new. It worried me.

The command:

```
$ docker run --name repo alpine/git clone https://github.com/docker/getting-started.git
$ cd getting-started
$ docker build -t docker101tutorial .
```

The problem is that, `alpine/git` image can write to the host directory, even without the `-v` flag.

As I was writing this SO, I checked the `alpine/git` image's Dockerfile.

The `alpine/git` image's Dockerfile contains `VOLUME [/git]` and `WORKDIR /git`. I expected that it will be stored in host directory `/getting-started` and not `~/getting-started`.

Comment: A Docker container does not have access to your local directory without an explicit `-v`. If I run the same command you show in your question it does not create a `getting-started` directory locally. It looks like you may have cloned the `getting-started` repository prior to running Docker. Do you see the same behavior if you explicitly delete the `getting-started` directory and then re-run the clone command?

Comment: @larsks My bad, the quick start guide did `$ docker cp repo:/git/getting-started/ .`